# How to set up a chjail enviroment

Tags: command-line, login

I've been searching throughout the web for instructions on creating a chjail"ed" user or terminal instance, but so far I could find none that would suit my preferences.

All I need is a terminal instance for a user to log in, and then restrict his activity to *his* section of the hard drive only. And is there a shell that's already precompiled to do so? The protocol would be SSH if you need additional information.

I also don't want any scripts like

```
while [ true ] ; do
printf "$" ; read command
$command
```

since the user could skip the initializing of that script.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10483796/1205368) could help

Comment: I'd have voted up your post if it were an answer.